# Open PowerPoint on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am the developer of *Android* and my language English not good.

My question is :

I need the `code` to the Android device, open *PowerPoint*.
And the Android device to display a *PowerPoint*.
Please explain how the `code` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use following code:

```
File file = new File("path_to_the_file.ppt");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
startActivity(intent);
```

And there is also a `Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents`. You can take look at [here](http://poi.apache.org).